# Robo-Copying files between google file stream and a network drive with a windows task scheduler gets “Access Denied”

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, google-drive-file-stream

I am trying to copy files that is generated by SAP Business Objects (and saved onto a network drive (M:)) onto the google file stream drive (G:). I used the Robocopy windows command, which enables me to skip files that are already there. My (simplified) batch file looks like this:

`@robocopy "M:\aFolder" "g:\My Drive\DataDrops" "*.txt" /XO >> Logfile.txt`

This works perfectly when I doubleclick it, or run it from cmd prompt. But I want to schedule it to basically check for new files every 10m or so. So I created a windows task to run the batch file. But when the task runs it, it pops up a cmd window that reads "access denied".

I set the task to run as myself, and only when I'm logged on to run, but somehow when the task runs it I get access denied. I don't know if the task is not allowed to access the network drive, or not the google file stream drive, or my local drive (which is where the script is saved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was to move it to powershell, and then schedule powershell (not the script itself) and then pass the script as a parameter.

So yeah: schedule powershell with the paramaters: `-executionpolicy bypass -file YourScript.ps1`

The second part of the fix is to not used mapped network drives but use the `\\servername\filepath\` notation in the networked file name, as apparently the scheduler didn't see the mapped drive. (The google drive still works so I'm stoked about that)